# Статистика использования разных разрешений экранов

Tags: android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти статистику использования телефонов с разным разрешением экранов на 2015-2016 год?

Comment: http://gs.statcounter.com/ а здесь не только телефоны а и десктопы, планшеты

Comment: @Cherevkian, это же по браузерам.

Answer (score 7):

[Android Dashboards](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/about/dashboards/index.html) - наиболее очевидное и достоверное место статистики по android-устройствам